# An expression or Idiom to describe feeling lost/ confused/ fuzzy?

Tags: expressions, idioms-in-context

Can you recommend me any idioms or common-sense expressions for **feeling lost/confused/fuzzy?**   I had the idea to use "being stranded on an island" (cause we had this usage in my mother language). Does it fit? Any other suggestions?

Comment: Common sense expressions would be "I feel lost" or "confused" or "fuzzy".  Is there a specfic situation that means that you need to use a figurative expression or simile?

Comment: _All at sea_ is an idiom for being confused or perplexed.

Comment: @JamesK I want to use an idiom or figurative expressions to describe the emotional atmosphere when a team feels lost, confused and fuzzy (when doing a collective work).  I have a paragraph describing this collective feeling. The idiom/ expression will help me to give a quick impression to the reader.

Comment: @KateBunting Didn't know that one! Thanks.